# SQL Server 2008 R2: Remove some part of string

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a query with order by clause as shown below.

```
SET @SQLquery = 'SELECT Cola,Colb FROM Test
              ORDER BY Cola DESC,Colb'
```

I have a variable which contain query with order by clause.

**Note**: I just want to remove order by clause `ORDER BY Cola DESC,Colb`. I may have multiple column in `ORDER BY` so basically the `@SQLQuery` will be **dynamic**.

Comment: Find position of `order by` substring with `charindex` and then use `left(@SQLquery, that_position)`

Comment: @AndyKorneyev, Yeah! Got it. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SET @SQLquery = LEFT(@SQLquery, PATINDEX('%ORDER BY%', @SQLquery) - 1)
```

If your are not sure whether `ORDER BY` is included in `@SQLquery` or not, then you could use:

```
SET @SQLquery = LEFT(@SQLquery, CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%ORDER BY%', @SQLquery) <> 0 
                                   THEN PATINDEX('%ORDER BY%', @SQLquery) -1
                                   ELSE LEN(@SQLquery)
                                 END)
```

Comment: OnePlus. Thank you so much. Will accept it within 9 minutes.

Comment: @MAK Glad I was able to help. Please also check the edit I made.

Comment: Wow! That is fantastic idea. Again thank you so much.